# Send Mail using Office 365 Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, office365

I am trying to send mail using office365 but it throw an error

**Failed to authenticate password. Error: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**

Code:

```
     //mail method 

     $configs = [        
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
            'smtp_user' => 'my_mail id',
            'smtp_pass' => 'my password',
            'smtp_crypto' => 'tls', 
            'smtp_port' => 587,
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'enable_starttls_auto' => true  ,
            'validation' =>FALSE,
            'smtp_timeout' => '7'
        ];

        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($configs);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");  
        $this->email->from('Joules to watts', 'Identification');
        $this->email->to("to_mail@gmail.com");
        $this->email->subject('testing');
        $this->email->message("testing");
        $sent = $this->email->send();
        if ($sent) 
        {
                echo 'OK';

        } else {
                echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
```

Are there any mistakes in code ?? Thanks

Comment: have you tried sending an email via command line? if you can't then you need to configure sendmail mail server. are you using amazon aws? private host? you can also contact your hosting company for help if your server can't send emails.

Comment: Email are going with gmail, but not with office365, Currenty working localhost.

Comment: aah, then you need to completely configure office365 before you start using any scripts. have you looked at the office365 documentation?

Comment: are you on windows or linux? your code seems to be well structured to do what its supposed to do.

Comment: I am using linux,

Comment: take a look at this when you can https://gordan.jandreoski.me/how-to-configure-postfix-relay-to-office365-on-ubuntu-14-04/ -- this may help

Comment: I think I need to do configuration settings in office 365

Comment: @unixmiah, I tried sending mail in laravel using above office 365 configuration and it worked, Still do I need to follow this  gordan.jandreoski.me/ documentaion??.

Comment: have you looked the the actual mail log when it fails for more information?

Comment: Yes I have mentioned the error